# How to create custom listview from two array strings in fragment?

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, android-arrayadapter

I was searching on Youtube and other questions on Google but didn't get the best result. I need to connect two **ArrayList** to **TextView** on XML, I did try this with two **arrayadapter**, but the result only affects one on the last of **arrayadapter**.  Maybe anyone here can help me with this case.

This is my **ShopFragment.java**

```
    public class ShopFragment extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_shop, container, false);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        ListView listView = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.product_list_view);

        ArrayList<String> name_of_product = new ArrayList<>();
        name_of_product.add("Tomat");
        name_of_product.add("Cabe");
        name_of_product.add("Wortel");
        name_of_product.add("Bayam");
        name_of_product.add("Sawi");
        name_of_product.add("Kangkung");

        ArrayList<String> price_of_product = new ArrayList<>();
        price_of_product.add("4000");
        price_of_product.add("5000");
        price_of_product.add("8000");
        price_of_product.add("6000");
        price_of_product.add("6000");
        price_of_product.add("6000");

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), R.layout.shop_row, R.id.product_name, name_of_product);


        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        if(position==0) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Tomat", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if(position==1) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Cabe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if(position==2) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Wortel", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if(position==3) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Bayam", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if(position==4) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Sawi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if(position==5) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Kangung", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

and this **shop_row.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="5">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Bayam"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/cyan_900"
            android:id="@+id/product_name"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.6">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Rp."
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:fontFamily="monospace"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textColor="@color/cyan_900"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.4">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="5000"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:fontFamily="monospace"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textColor="@color/cyan_900"
            android:id="@+id/product_price"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I just want **name_of_product** and **price_of_product** can connect with **product_name** and **product_price** on xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), R.layout.shop_row, R.id.product_name, name_of_product);
```

to

```
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.shop_row, name_of_product) {
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
            convertView = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            TextView tvName = convertView.findViewById(R.id.product_name);
            TextView tvPrice = convertView.findViewById(R.id.product_price);
            tvName.setText(name_of_product.get(position));
            tvPrice.setText(price_of_product.get(position));
            return convertView;
        }
    };
```

Comment: it's still crash when open that fragment